How does NestJS use ES imports natively but doesn't support ES modules?
I'm a bit confused about ES module usage in NestJS. If I create a project from scratch, it uses ES Modules:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma/prisma.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

Yet, if I create a module that uses ES imports and then import it into my NestJS project, I get errors saying "export" is not a recognized keyword (and I've read multiple times online that NestJS does not support ES modules). So, my question is, how does it support it internally but not when using outside modules? Or is my understanding of export/import and ES modules just wrong?
